# Clarification about navigation controllers : Why aren't all my controllers under it's influence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that did NOT use navigation controllers. We decided we wanted to add them and took the first controller and embedded it in a navigation controller.

Now, some of the controllers (in storyboard) appear with a bar, and then a few segues later, they're out of the navigation controller's "reach". As if it wasn't there.

We thought about adding more but it just seems confusing and wrong, i'm guessing we should only have one, right?

Our app has different types of segue (modal & push) but when i look at the flow of controllers in the app, it's the navigation controller stops appearing with no specific pattern.

Also, once we reach the view where the NC is gone, it doesn't come back later in the flow (obviously).

Comment: If you have a **modal** segue it will cover up the navigation bar

Comment: There is no modal at that point ; even the preview in storyboard shows no nav bar (yet it does in previous controllers). And there is no difference between all those controllers

Comment: In the storyboard under the property of controllers you can choose the navigation bar. Have you checked if they are all set to the same thing?